# How to manage node.js microservices development enviornment

Tags: node.js, express, microservices

I am working on a project which will have more than 5 NODE.JS microservices so my question is how do i setup the development environment right now i have to start each service manually one by one in terminal and then i start doing development and modifies the code to reflect the changes i use nodemon and expressjs for each microservices.

Please guide me.

Comment: What do you want to improve about your current setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to operate your running node processes in bulk.

If you want more advanced control over the process - use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) or [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) to conteinerize your app.

Answer (score 0):

> so my question is how do i setup the development environment right now
>   i have to start each service manually one by one in terminal

Well, this is not the intention of "microservice". Your microservice A's deployment should **NOT** require microservice B's deployment, otherwise you are better off with a monolith. In other words, you should be able to point your Microservice A to Microservice B at (higher) environment. (For example, your Microservice A at dev should be able to point to Microservice B at staging)

**How will we achieve that?** one way is develop and deploy Microservice B ahead of Microservice A development (of course , newer version of Microservice B cannot break backward compatibility in this method.)

If you are in dire need of parallel development in 2 of your microservices for a feature, what you can do is, set up a CI-CD environment and deploy continuously to a dev environment (I am assuming you are using git, just keep deploying to your dev environment from your feature/dev branch instead of master branch) Then from your local Microservice A , point to dev microservice B

Comment: Yes, I am using git. How do I reflect my changes instantly during development to microservices?